# top-level-await error when using NextJS API

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, next.js

I'm building an api with NextJS and MongoDB. I do a basic setup on the top of the API file:

```js
const { db } = await connectToDatabase();
const scheduled = db.collection('scheduled');
```

and I continue the code with my handler function:

```js
export default async function handler(req, res) {
  otherFunctionCalls()
  ...
}

const otherFunctionCalls = async () => {
  ...
}
```

I know await will work only within an async function, but I would like to use the `scheduled` constant in other functions what the handler calls, that's why I need to call it on the top.

If I put the constant to every single function, then it's code duplication.

What's the best practice to access to `scheduled` constant? Should I add the `otherFunctionCalls` declaration into the handler function?

The complete error what I got:

```
Module parse failed: The top-level-await experiment is not enabled (set experiments.topLevelAwait: true to enabled it)
File was processed with these loaders:
 * ./node_modules/next/dist/build/babel/loader/index.js
You may need an additional loader to handle the result of these loaders.
Error: The top-level-await experiment is not enabled (set experiments.topLevelAwait: true to enabled it)
```

Comment: *"I know await will work only within an async function..."* Well, no, that's the point of top-level `await` -- it works at the top level of a module, outside an `async` function.

Comment: As the error message is telling you, you can only use top-level `await` if you enable it in the tool giving you that error, because it's still experimental in whatever tool is showing you that error message. (Top-level `await` is [**not** experimental anymore](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-top-level-await) in JavaScript itself, but it's quite new, and some tools are still catching up.)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder My bad, thanks for the heads-up

Comment: @T.J.Crowder yes, for that reason I would like to go with an other solution

Comment: Would you update the question to say that? I didn't understand that from the question at all. Thanks. :-)

Answer (score 1):

In the comments you've said you want to find another solution rather than enabling the top-level `await` experiment in the tool you're using.

To do that, you'll have to adjust the module code to handle the fact that you don't have the `scheduled` collection yet, you just have a *promise* of it. If the only exported function is `handler` and all of the other functions are going to be called from `handler`, they it makes sense to handle that (no pun!) in `handler`, along these lines:

```
// A promise for the `scheduled` collection
const pScheduled = connectToDatabase().then(db => db.collection("scheduled"));

export default async function handler(req, res) {
    const scheduled = await pScheduled;
    await otherFunctionCalls(scheduled);
    // ...
}

const otherFunctionCalls = async (scheduled) => {
    // ...use `scheduled` here...
};
```

There are lots of ways you might tweak that, but fundamentally you'll want to get the promise (just once is fine) and `await` it to get its fulfillment value anywhere you need its fulfillment value. (For the avoidance of double: `await` doesn't re-run anything; if the promise is already fulfilled, it just gives you back the fulfillment value the promise already has.)